# How to manually set timestamp for Splunk logs?

Tags: javascript, logging, splunk

I have a database table full of logs, and I would like to upload that into Splunk by executing a query to get an array of logs, then iterating over it and running `console.log()` on each log. This almost works fine, however the timestamp that Splunk picks up for each log is based on whatever time I run the upload script.

Is there any way I can transform my log object so that Splunk will use the timestamps I provide? For example, one of my logs might look like:

```
{
  id: 2910432221,
  log_timestamp: 2019-08-07T19:04:03.000Z,
  userId: 2331,
  actionId: 45
}
```

Ideally, I would be able to run something like this, and have the value of `splunk_timestamp` appear in the `Time` column in the Splunk dashboard.

```
console.log({
 id: 2910432221,
 splunk_timestamp: 2019-08-07T19:04:03.000Z,
 userId: 2331,
 actionId: 45
})
```

Is anything like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splunk will try to automatically identify the `_time` value by picking the first field it encounters matching `TIME_FORMAT`. You can override this in `props.conf`.

I believe your problem is in the `json` object: what you are passing to `console.log` is **not** a valid json object. Field names and values should be properly quoted.

```
{
 "id": 2910432221,
 "splunk_timestamp": "2019-08-07T19:04:03.000Z",
 "userId": 2331,
 "actionId": 45
}
```